# How to send IR data from Arduino to USB-TTL

Tags: arduino-uno, rs232, node.js, infrared

I have a led receiver KY-022 and led emitter KY-005, I also have a PL2303 (USB-TTL). This is the code of the issuing LED:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
     irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12); // Sony TV power code
     //Serial.print(0xa90,HEX);
     delay(40);
   }
}
```

The following is the connection scheme:
[image]

The output of the KY-022 I have connected to the pin RXD of the PL2303 which has a led that indicates that it receives data, however when using the HyperTerminal program to see the data I receive nothing appears.

I found similar [information](https://robosumo.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/simple-usb-receiver-for-ir-data-using-pl2303hx-and-gp1ux31qs/) but they use another LED model, however I think it should work the same. What can I do?

I'm also testing with node js using the node js package, but in the console I only get non-readable characters, or something like this `Buffer 00 e0 e0 e0 e0` if I do not apply toString () to the data.

This is my code in node JS.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM9", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline("\n")
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnected', function(){
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

var clearData = "";
var readData = "";

serialPort.on('open',function(){
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        readData += data.toString();
        io.sockets.emit('message',data);
    });
});
```

Comment: please post the code that you are using for receiving the IR data

Comment: I have no code for the KY-022, it is directly connected to PL2303.  I only have the node code js with which I read what enters the RX pin.

Comment: You don't have much of a clue about how IR communication works, do you? IR != serial. You need something between the receiver and your computer that decodes the incoming IR signal and converts it into something more meaningful. At the moment you're pointing a TV remote control at a fish and expecting it to bark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are transmitting data by encoding it using one of probably many Sony Consumer Remote Control formats and expecting to decode it using one of many possible RS232 like formats.  You will likely get something between nothing and random values.

Instead, consider sending data using only the RS232 protocols.  This is what is done [in this tutorial](http://www.electronicwings.com/arduino/ir-communication-using-arduino-uno).  It is recommended you replicate the tutorial before moving on to using a TTL to USB dongle and a computer.  This should validate the transmitter is working.  Note in the tutorial transmitter code example no IR  remote control library is used.  Only the common serial libraries.

A word regarding the tutorial.  Consider using the second of the two examples in the tutorial.  The first does not modulate the IR transmitter and will not work with commonly available IR receivers.  The second does modulate the IR transmitter and discusses how to alter the modulation to accommodate different IR receivers.